# stop scrolling on bookmark hyperlink clickin

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I am trying to make a jquery similar tabs. since its for single use in single page i dun want to use jquery so i am making my custom function.

I have my li tags as following

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tabs-0" onclick="showTabs(this); void(0);" class="active">Description</a></li>
```

My function gets fired and is working fine... but a small problem is that page scrolls upto the bookmark location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tabs-0" onclick="showTabs(this); return false;" class="active">Description</a></li>
```

`return false;` is preventing the default behavior from happening.

Comment: thnx gr8... it helped alot... thnx for saving my time... :)

Comment: i couldnt do it before 11 mins so went offline for sometime... thxn once more